# Extract schema labels from pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

From a pyspark dataframe I want to create a python list with the schema labels for a specific schema "level".

The schema is:

```
root
 |-- DISPLAY: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 1WO: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- JPY: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CHANGE24HOUR: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CHANGEDAY: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- AAVE: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- JPY: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CHANGE24HOUR: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CHANGEDAY: string (nullable = true)
```

The expected output is:

```
list = 1WO, AAVE
```

The following code print everything in the schema:

```
df.schema.jsonValue()
```

Is there an easy way to extract those labels pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the first layer using the asterisk notation, and the n list the columns:

`df.select('DISPLAY.*').columns`